# Why does running the tutorial example fail with Rstan?

Tags: r, rstan

I installed the RStan successfully, the library loads. I try to run a tutorial example (https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/RStan-Getting-Started#example-1-eight-schools). After applying the `stan` function

```
fit1 <- stan(
  file = "schools.stan",  # Stan program
  data = schools_data,    # named list of data
  chains = 4,             # number of Markov chains
  warmup = 1000,          # number of warmup iterations per chain
  iter = 2000,            # total number of iterations per chain
  cores = 1,              # number of cores (could use one per chain)
  refresh = 0             # no progress shown
)
```

I get the following error:

```
*Error in compileCode(f, code, language = language, verbose = verbose) : 
  C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: file1c34165764a4.o:file1c34165764a4.cpp:(.text$_ZN3tbb8internal26task_scheduler_observer_v3D0Ev[_ZN3tbb8internal26task_scheduler_observer_v3D0Ev]+0x1d): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::task_scheduler_observer_v3::observe(bool)'C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: file1c34165764a4.o:file1c34165764a4.cpp:(.text$_ZN3tbb10interface623task_scheduler_observerD1Ev[_ZN3tbb10interface623task_scheduler_observerD1Ev]+0x1d): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::task_scheduler_observer_v3::observe(bool)'C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: file1c34165764a4.o:file1c34165764a4.cpp:(.text$_ZN3tbb10interface623task_scheduler_observerD1Ev[_ZN3tbb10interface623task_scheduler_observerD1Ev]+0x3a): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::task_scheduler_observer_v3::observe(bool)'C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: file1c34165764a4.o:file1c34165764a4.cpp:(.text$_ZN3tbb10interface
Error in sink(type = "output") : invalid connection*
```

Simply running `example(stan_model, run.dontrun=T)` gives the same error.

What does this error mean?

Is rtools wrongly installed? My PATH seems to contain the correct folder `C:\\rtools42\\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\\bin;`. Is something wrong with the version of my Rstan package? I am struggling to interpret this error?

What to try to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Rtools42 in incompatible with the current version Rstan on CRAN. The solution that worked for me is found here: https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/Configuring-C---Toolchain-for-Windows#r-42